# Check whether the user is already logged in or not

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a web application developed on Servlet-JSP MVC which runs on a internal server and the problem scenario is as below.

If the end user enter the site url,the application will ask for login credentials and i am checking the credentials in a LoginController.

Consider the situation when the user enter the credentials and login into the application and then closes the browser window,if the user again types the url it will again ask for the login credentials.

Now i want my application to remember whether a user is logged in or not,only ask for the login credentials if the user is already not logged in.

How can i implement this?Any suggestions on what can be done will be helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

The browser has to store the information if the user is logged in.
You could use cookies for that.

You can simply store a value that says: No need to check for password.
Or you can store the username in the cookie and send it to the server which checks if the user is logged in and then replies the result to the browser.

Comment: *"You can simply store a value that says: No need to check for password"* So you mean I only need to create such cookie manually to bypass a password check? That doesn't sound secure.

Comment: True. But do you need that much security on an internal server?

Comment: "internal server" is no protection. Just because the amount of people is limited, it doesn't mean that you can trust all of them. Especially if it is that easy to bad things.

Comment: Security is not that important,suggest me a way how can i do this?